# Как сделать множественную загрузку файлов с сайта?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, form, upload

форма

```
<form action="feedback/index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="sendMassage" name="form-2">
<input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя">
<input name="tell" type="text" placeholder="Номер телефона">
<input name="e-mail" type="text" placeholder="e-mail">
<div class="file-upload"><label><input type="file" name="file" multiple><span><span>+</span> Прикрепить файл</span></label></div>
<input class="feedback" name="send" type="button" value="Отправить обращение"></form>
```

php

```
// Перехват файла с формы
var files = '', fileName = '';
// Получим данные файлов и добавим их в переменную
$(document).on('change', 'input[type=file]', function(){
  var file = this.files[0];
  fileName = $(this).val();
  fileName = fileName.split('\\'); 
  fileName = fileName[fileName.length - 1]; 
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (e) { 
     files = e.target.result 
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);

  if($('.fileName').length == 0) $('.file-upload').before('<div class="fileName"></div>');
  $('.fileName').html(fileName+'<span id="delFile">X</span>');

});

$(document).on('click', '#delFile', function(){
  var inp = $('input[type="file"]').clone();
  $('input[type="file"]').before(inp).remove();
  $('.fileName').remove();
});

function base64_encode(data) {

  var b64 = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=';
  var o1, o2, o3, h1, h2, h3, h4, bits, i = 0,
    ac = 0,
    enc = '',
    tmp_arr = [];

  if (!data) {
    return data;
  }

  do { // pack three octets into four hexets
    o1 = data.charCodeAt(i++);
    o2 = data.charCodeAt(i++);
    o3 = data.charCodeAt(i++);

    bits = o1 << 16 | o2 << 8 | o3;

    h1 = bits >> 18 & 0x3f;
    h2 = bits >> 12 & 0x3f;
    h3 = bits >> 6 & 0x3f;
    h4 = bits & 0x3f;

    // use hexets to index into b64, and append result to encoded string
    tmp_arr[ac++] = b64.charAt(h1) + b64.charAt(h2) + b64.charAt(h3) + b64.charAt(h4);
  } while (i < data.length);

  enc = tmp_arr.join('');

  var r = data.length % 3;

  return (r ? enc.slice(0, r - 3) : enc) + '==='.slice(r || 3);
}
// сохранение файла
    if(isset($_POST['file'])){
      $file = base64_decode($_POST['file[]']);
      $file = explode(',', $file);
      $file = base64_decode($file[1]);
      $fileName = date('YmdHis').'_'.$_POST['fName'];
      $fp = fopen(''.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-content/themes/vesta/assets/feedback//uploads/'.$fileName.'', 'w');
      // записываем в файл текст
      fwrite($fp, $file);
      // закрываем
      fclose($fp);
      $href = domain($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']).'/wp-content/themes/vesta/assets/feedback//uploads/'.$fileName;
    $sb['body'] .= 'Скачать файл(ы): <a href="'.$href.'" target="_blank">'.$fileName.'</a>';
    }
```

js

```
// Перехват файла с формы
var files = '', fileName = '';
// Получим данные файлов и добавим их в переменную
$(document).on('change', 'input[type=file]', function(){
  var file = this.files[0];
  fileName = $(this).val();
  fileName = fileName.split('\\'); 
  fileName = fileName[fileName.length - 1]; 
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (e) { 
     files = e.target.result 
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);

  if($('.fileName').length == 0) $('.file-upload').before('<div class="fileName"></div>');
  $('.fileName').html(fileName+'<span id="delFile">X</span>');

});

$(document).on('click', '#delFile', function(){
  var inp = $('input[type="file"]').clone();
  $('input[type="file"]').before(inp).remove();
  $('.fileName').remove();
});

function base64_encode(data) {

  var b64 = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=';
  var o1, o2, o3, h1, h2, h3, h4, bits, i = 0,
    ac = 0,
    enc = '',
    tmp_arr = [];

  if (!data) {
    return data;
  }

  do { // pack three octets into four hexets
    o1 = data.charCodeAt(i++);
    o2 = data.charCodeAt(i++);
    o3 = data.charCodeAt(i++);

    bits = o1 << 16 | o2 << 8 | o3;

    h1 = bits >> 18 & 0x3f;
    h2 = bits >> 12 & 0x3f;
    h3 = bits >> 6 & 0x3f;
    h4 = bits & 0x3f;

    // use hexets to index into b64, and append result to encoded string
    tmp_arr[ac++] = b64.charAt(h1) + b64.charAt(h2) + b64.charAt(h3) + b64.charAt(h4);
  } while (i < data.length);

  enc = tmp_arr.join('');

  var r = data.length % 3;

  return (r ? enc.slice(0, r - 3) : enc) + '==='.slice(r || 3);
}
$(document).on('click', '.feedback', function(){
    var form = $(this).closest('form'), 
      name = form.attr('name'),
      obj = {},
      formData = $(form).serialize();

    // прикрепление файлов
    if(files != '') formData = formData+'&file='+base64_encode(files)+'&fName='+fileName;

    obj.form = form;
    obj.act = name;
    obj.data = formData;

    feedback(obj);
    return false;
  });
```

Код не мой, я в php не знаток, сейчас файл прикрепляется к форме и отправляется как нужно, но только один файл приходит на почту, а хотелось бы выбирать несколько файлов. Помогите как переделать форму.

Comment: Разделите в вашем вопросе код, как положено. На данный момент у вас все напутано, js код вы называете php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно в цикле перебирать массив `$_FILES['file']` и для каждого файла вызывать код, который сохранит его в нужную директорию:

```php
if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $key => $name) {
        $dir = '/wp-content/themes/vesta/assets/feedback//uploads/';
        $fileName = date('YmdHis') . '_' . $name;
        $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $dir . $fileName;

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key], $path)) {
            $href = domain($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) . $dir . $fileName;
            $sb['body'] .= 'Скачать файл(ы): <a href="' . $href . '" target="_blank">' . $fileName . '</a>';
        }
    }
}
```